# Distinguish between iframe redirect and refresh

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a service which loads third party content to my page using `iframe`. I have no access to modify the page i'm loading within the iframe.

I have to refresh the page which hosts the iframe in case the page within `iframe` gets refreshed. I do not want to refresh the parent page in case there's a redirect inside the `iframe`. Which essentially boils down to me having to differentiate between page redirect and page refresh inside the `iframe` element.

My initial thought was to use the `onload` event, but due to CORS issues, i'm unable to actually determine the source of the page it opened (so I cannot track whether it reloaded or redirected).

Is there a way to distinguish between page redirect and page refresh within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

the difference between reload and refresh. is that reload is (computing) to refresh a copy of a program in memory or of a web page on the screen while a refresh is (computing) the update of a display (in a web browser or similar software) to show the latest version of the data.